# mongodb $match and $nin with _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My code:

```
questionSchema.statics.getRandomByUser = function getRandomByUser(user) {
  const aggr = [{ $sample: { size: 1 } }];
  console.log(`user.answered = ${user.answered}`);
  if (user.answered.length || user.categories.length) {
    const match = { $match: {} };
    if (user.answered.length) match.$match._id = { $nin: user.answered };
    if (user.categories.length) match.$match.category = { $in: user.categories };
    aggr.unshift(match);
  }

  console.log(`aggr = ${JSON.stringify(aggr)}`);
  return this.model('question').aggregate(aggr);
};
```

In result aggregate is:

```
[{"$match":{"_id":{"$nin":["5c7bb1d08f999f326151df49","5c7bb1d08f999f326151df49"]},"category":{"$in":["Test"]}}},{"$sample":{"size":1}}]
```

Filter by category works fine. But my `$nin` just ignored. How I must use `$nin` with `_id` to omit unwanted documents?

Comment: Even though this is marked as [duplicate], I think the question is very useful, because it deals with $nin. There are not a lot of examples of $nin. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_id` in mongoDb is usually an `ObjectId` which is a 24 charachter hexadecimal unique key.

You can convert the string _id to ObjectId and then query

```
[{"$match":{"_id":{"$nin":[ObjectId("5c7bb1d08f999f326151df49"),ObjectId("5c7bb1d08f999f326151df49")]},"category":{"$in":["Test"]}}},{"$sample":{"size":1}}]
```

Comment: so what will the best solution? save `ObjectId`'s in array or create additional index (as I did now)?

Comment: @MikitaMelnikau from what I understand, If your unique key in `user ` i.e _id is an ObjectId, you should convert your id from string to ObjectId in your script. MongoDb by default, sets _id as an ObjectId, not as plain string like you are querying.

Comment: _id is by default ,indexed in mongo. Just make sure your data types are correct.